# Angular 2 / typescript pass service into promise

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

How can I pass in a service to a promise?  I am trying to create a promise that will resolve when all the http request come back.  Right now this.jiraService is undefined.  Is there anyway to pass it to the constructor of the promise?

```
export class JiraComponent {
private stories:Map<string,number> = new Map<string,number>();

constructor(private jiraService:JiraService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.jiraService.search()
        .then(x => this.getKeys(x['issues']))
        .then(keys => this.getLogs(keys))
        .then(x => console.log(this.stories));
}

getKeys(issues:Array<Object>) {
    let keys = new Array<string>();
    for (var i of issues) {
        keys.push(i['key']);
    }
    return keys;
}

getLogs(keys:Array<string>) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let count = 0;
        for (var k of keys) {
            this.jiraService.worklog(keys[0]).then(x => {
                count++;
                console.log(x);
                if (!this.stories.get(k)) {
                    this.stories.set(k, x['timeSpentSeconds']);
                }
                else {
                    this.stories.set(k, this.stories.get(k) + x['timeSpentSeconds']);
                }
                if (count == keys.length) {
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/294949

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble accessing the `this` object within the executor function of your Promise, [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback/20279485#20279485) may help you out (mentioned above by danh).

However, this isn't the canonical structure for an Angular 2 app, and that may be the source of some of your troubles.  A good place to start is the official [Angular 2 Style Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#)'s discussion of Components and Services (it's all worth a read, though!).

**Services make promises**

Typically, a Component should not be making any Promises at all.  The service presents your Component(s) with an endpoint to access business logic and/or data services (databases, external APIs, etc.).

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    private allIsGood: boolean;

    public doSomething(): Promise<any> {
        console.log("I promise to return at some point.");
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            this.allIsGood = someLongRunningActivity();
            if (this.allIsGood) {
                console.log("Resolving the promise.");
                resolve();
            } else {
                console.log("Something bad happened, don't forget to check for errors!");
                reject();
            }
        });
    }

    private someLongRunningActivity(): boolean {
        //run a query or perform some calculation
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Components receive promises**

Components should call a service and consume it's returned Promise.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from '../services';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-selector',
    templateUrl: 'my template.html'
})
export class MyComponent {

    constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        this.myService.doSomething()
            .then(() => {
                console.log("The promise was honored, you can do what you were waiting to do.");
            })
            .catch(() => {
                console.log("You remembered to check for errors!");
            });
    });
}
```

A few caveats:

- This assumes you've set up your Providers correctly during the initial bootstrap process!
- Paths to your imports may vary...

I'm only allowed to post two links, so I can't provide any more good references.  Read up on Promises and Observables at the Angular 2 documentation site from above.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What about using `Promise.All([p1, p2, p3])` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

This doesn't answer your question directly, but I think it will achieve what you want from your getter